# How do you change the password for the keyring manager in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome

I don't have the password for the keyring manager?

Can I delete the keyring to renew the password or are there any other ways of stopping the keyring manager from prompting before accessing programs that use the keyring manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found:

you can delete the keyring that you have forgotten the password for which results in you being prompted for a new keyring password.

1. on the command line use locate default.keyring to find the location of your keyring folder.
2. delete the keyring you have forgotten the password for.
3. restart machine.
4. next time you access a program you will be prompted to enter a new password for the keyring

Answer (score 2):

uninstall it, that should stop it from popping up.

btw, should the password be the same as the one you use to login?

Comment: "btw, should the password be the same as the one you use to login?" thats what I thought, but no, something could have corrupted it

Answer (score 1):

You can use seahorse to manage your keyrings (yes, plural; you can have more than one). It can create and delete keyrings, as well as change the password of an existing keyring.